# How can I add Elements permanently using jquery then it will add the number incremently e.g Cam 1, Cam 2, Cam 3, etc. Using iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]So, I have a video streaming in my website. I have a default Cam 1 which this is the code:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> &nbsp;CCTV
        <span class="float-right" id="addcam"><a href="#" onclick="addCamera();">+ add camera</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" id="camera-body">
        <p><strong>Cam 1</strong></p>
        <iframe id="cam1" class="container-fluid mb-4" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D-EcyYkv-mU"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click the (+ add camera), it will call the js function `addCamera();`

Here's my code in my js script (jquery):

```
<script>
        function addCamera() {
            <?php $camNumber = 1; $camNumber += $camNumber; ?>
            $("div#camera-body").append("<hr id=\"remove\" style=\"border: 0.2px solid black;\">");
            $("div#camera-body").append("<p id=\"remove\"><strong><?php echo h("Cam " . $camNumber) ?></strong><a href=\"#\" class=\"float-right mr-3\" onclick=\"removeCamera();\" style=\"color:black;\">X</a></p>");
            $("div#camera-body").append("<iframe id=\"remove\" class=\"container-fluid mb-4\" height=\"500\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed\"></iframe>");
        }

        function removeCamera() {
            $("iframe#remove, p#remove, hr#remove").remove();
        }
</script>
```

How can I increment the number of cam when I add? And also I put an (x) on the top right when adding a camera so there's an option if you want to delete the cam you added. The first/default cam will not be deleted though.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: `<?php $camNumber = 1; $camNumber += $camNumber; ?>` - apart from that this makes rather limited sense to begin with ... you will of course have to increase the counter on the client side, in your JavaScript, _using_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now but the incrementing only on Camera numbers. Here's my code:

```
<script>
        var camNum = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        camNum.length;
        function addCamera() {
            $("div#camera-body").append("<p><strong>Cam " + camNum.length + "</strong></p><iframe class=\"container-fluid mb-4\" height=\"500\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed\"></iframe>");
        }
</script>
```